# Is it legal in India to disallow food and water to be brought in to a public place?

Tags: india, food

In some cities in India, the malls having movie theaters do not allow people to bring their own food or even water inside the movie theater. When I say their own food it includes the food or water bought outside the theater also. They even check your bags for verifying this.

I want to know if this is legal. Is it not a basic right to carry any harmless things anywhere? What right do they have to object that? After all, it is a public place and I bought the ticket. Food and water are basic needs, how can someone restrict that?

Being said that, I understand the reason why the theater management want to restrict it. They sell highly overpriced(more than 5x for popcorn) snacks and drinks inside the theater. They make more money on these than on the ticket itself. But still I want to know if what they are doing is legal?

If state laws come in to picture, Telangana is the state I am interested to know about.

Comment: Since this is more likely a matter of state laws, you should specify one.

Comment: What makes you think that movie theaters are public places? Just because public is allowed in? Somebody owns them, and they are free to set rules of entry.